# Выравнивание TextView и ImageView по center_vertical

Tags: xml, android, java, android-ui, android-layout

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выровнять два вью по центру лейаута по вертикали?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_action"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_action_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/bung_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/action_change_sphere_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Например, `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 1):

```
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  - прижимает к левому краю 
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" - прижимает к началу
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" - прижимает к верхнему краю
```

Вам нужно заменить свою разметку, на эту. Наиболее подробней о  RelativeLayout [тут](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_action"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_action_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/bung_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:src="@drawable/action_change_sphere_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```