# Как отцентрировать textview по вертикали?

Tags: android, xaml

Мне нужно отцентрировать tview3 по вертикали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу это сделать, не используя высоту match_parent т.к. размер секции в лейауте определяется размером tview2? Пробовал так:

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tview1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="text"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tview2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:text="wdd dwdwwfwfwfwfwf efef grg rgrg rgrgrgrg rgrgrgrgr tjghfgvb dfgdfgserg"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tview3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть небольшая [разница](https://overcoder.net/q/4051/%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8-layoutgravity-%D0%B2-android) между `gravity` и `layout_gravity`: первый задаёт ориентацию содержимого, а второй задаёт ориентацию контейнера относительно родителя.

Вы используете `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` для своего `TextView`, поэтому для решения Вашей задачи следует заменить `android:gravity="center_vertical"` на `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`.

Comment: Попробовал, но в отображении ничего не изменилось, в LinearLayoute такая центровка вроде работает, для RelativeLayouta как-то можно сделать также?

Comment: @Nonameguy прочтите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/313335)